# how to for each loop on data table within another datatable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, foreach, datatable

I have a web poll application that reads and processes orders from sql server back end and inserts into windss(jda).

the flow

1) I read all the orders from the sql server tables that is not processed
2) then I need to divide the orders into two sets
  - set 1 orders with bundle kit( 1 order with several suborders)
- set 2 is just orders with no bundle kit
3) then after each order is processed I need to update the isprocessed sql field to 1

1) code for reading all orders

Frmmain.vb

```
 dt = WebDatabase.GetAllOrdersFromDatabase()**'this method is below**

 For Each drow In dt.Rows
    If CDbl(WinDSSStoreNumber) = 123 Or CDbl(WinDSSStoreNumber) = 124 Then 
     ' Store 123 and 124 = customer service - only orders with qualifying source codes
```

**my question is:**

the above for each checks if the store is 123 or 124 but now  I want to implement another for each loop that reads all the InvoiceHeader_Id that the second field in the datatable and then check if it has a bundle kit or not if it does then process it and update the isprocessed field second last in the datatable else process the orders without any bundle kit and update isprocessed for those as well. please any help is generously appreciated, please ask me any questions in the below comment before marking my question down.

WebData.vb

```vb
    Public Function GetAllOrdersFromDatabase() As DataTable
            DrivePath = "C:\Users\somjething\Documents\files\somefiles\"
            Dim ds As DataTable = Nothing
            WinDSS.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WinDSS_Connection").Replace("%DrivePath%", DrivePath)
            ds = WinDSS.GetSysMst()

            If ds.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                WinDSSStoreNumber = ds.Rows(0)("store_no")

            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebData_Connection") & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebDataSource"))
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            conn.Open()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText= SELECT InvoiceDetail_Id, InvoiceHeader_Id, ActualFreightCharge, AmountCollected, 
        ChargedActualFreight, CollectedExternally, CollectedThroughAR, DateInvoiced, InvoiceNo, 
        InvoiceType, LineSubTotal, MasterInvoiceNo, OrderInvoiceKey, Reference1, TotalAmount, 
        TotalTax, isprocessed, storetoprocess
            FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader 
        WHERE (isprocessed = 0) AND (storetoprocess = N'123')
  da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        Return dt
    End Function
```

Additoinal info

This is the information given to me by my manager:

loop throught each below

```vb
SELECT InvoiceDetail_Id, InvoiceHeader_Id, ActualFreightCharge, AmountCollected, 
ChargedActualFreight, CollectedExternally, CollectedThroughAR, DateInvoiced, InvoiceNo, 
InvoiceType, LineSubTotal, MasterInvoiceNo, OrderInvoiceKey, Reference1, TotalAmount, 
TotalTax, isprocessed, storetoprocess
FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader WHERE (isprocessed = 0) AND (storetoprocess = N'195')
```

Use the above InvoiceHeader_Id to loop throught all of the order information. Process each Bundle (Kit/)

```vb
SELECT InvoiceHeader_Id, LineDetails_Id, LineDetail_Id, OrderLine_Id, GiftFlag, [References],
 GiftWrap, IsBundleParent, KitCode, KitQty, LevelOfService, LineSeqNo, LineType, 
MaxLineStatus, MaxLineStatusDesc, MinLineStatus, MinLineStatusDesc, MinShipByDate,
 OpenQty, OrderHeaderKey, OrderLineKey, OrderedQty, OriginalOrderedQty, OtherCharges,
 OverallStatus, PipelineKey, PrimeLineNo, ReceivingNode, RemainingQty, ReqCancelDate,
 ReqDeliveryDate, 
ReqShipDate, SCAC, ScacAndService, ScacAndServiceKey, ShipNode, ShipToID, ShipToKey,
 StatusQuantity, SubLineNo, SubstituteItemID, isprocessed
FROM dbo.OrderLine 
WHERE (isprocessed = 0) AND (InvoiceHeader_Id = 13) AND (IsBundleParent = 'Y')
ORDER BY PrimeLineNo, SubLineNo
```

For each record in the above list query below and add as Zero (0) dollar amount.  The cost is associated with the information above record (you may have to query tables to ge the values)
Get the OrderLineKey  from the above record and query this below to get the associated sub items.

```vb
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.BundleParentLine.InvoiceHeader_Id AS BPL_InvoiceHeader_Id, 
dbo.BundleParentLine.LineDetails_Id AS BPL_LineDetails_Id, dbo.BundleParentLine.LineDetail_Id AS BPL_LineDetail_Id, dbo.BundleParentLine.OrderLine_Id AS BPL_OrderLine_Id, dbo.BundleParentLine.BundleParentLine_id, dbo.BundleParentLine.SubLineNo AS BPL_SubLineNo, dbo.BundleParentLine.PrimeLineNo AS BPL_PrimeLineNo, dbo.BundleParentLine.OrderLineKey AS BPL_OrderLineKey, dbo.OrderLine.*
FROM dbo.BundleParentLine INNER JOIN dbo.OrderLine ON dbo.BundleParentLine.OrderLine_Id = dbo.OrderLine.OrderLine_Id AND dbo.BundleParentLine.LineDetail_Id = dbo.OrderLine.LineDetail_Id AND dbo.BundleParentLine.LineDetails_Id = dbo.OrderLine.LineDetails_Id AND dbo.BundleParentLine.InvoiceHeader_Id = dbo.OrderLine.InvoiceHeader_Id
WHERE (dbo.BundleParentLine.OrderLineKey = N'76873264832') AND (dbo.BundleParentLine.InvoiceHeader_Id = 13) AND (dbo.BundleParentLine.LineDetails_Id = 6)  AND  (dbo.OrderLine.isprocessed = 0)
ORDER BY BPL_PrimeLineNo, BPL_SubLineNo
```

After Processed, set isprocessed = 1

Use the above InvoiceHeader_Id to loop throught all of the order information

```vb
SELECT InvoiceHeader_Id, LineDetails_Id, LineDetail_Id, OrderLine_Id, GiftFlag, [References],
 GiftWrap, IsBundleParent, KitCode, KitQty, LevelOfService, LineSeqNo, 
 LineType,
 MaxLineStatus, MaxLineStatusDesc, MinLineStatus, MinLineStatusDesc, MinShipByDate,
 OpenQty, OrderHeaderKey, OrderLineKey, OrderedQty, 
  OriginalOrderedQty, 
OtherCharges, OverallStatus, PipelineKey, PrimeLineNo, ReceivingNode, RemainingQty, 
ReqCancelDate, ReqDeliveryDate, ReqShipDate, SCAC, 
 ScacAndService,
 ScacAndServiceKey, ShipNode, ShipToID, ShipToKey, StatusQuantity, 
SubLineNo, SubstituteItemID, isprocessed
FROM   dbo.OrderLine
WHERE (isprocessed = 0) AND (InvoiceHeader_Id = 13) AND (IsBundleParent <> 'Y')
ORDER BY PrimeLineNo, SubLineNo
```

After Processed, set isprocessed = 1

Comment: You really need to start thinking in sets. What you are describing sounds a lot like a single update statement to me. No need to loop through this row by agonizing row. Simply update the rows you need using a where predicate.

Comment: @SeanLange sets actually makes sense but how will I be using it in the above context? I am getting all the orders into a datatable so how can I now split bundlekit and non bundle kit into sets, I have both queries with the where condition all set but I am not sure how to filter from the datatable.

Comment: From what you described you don't need to pull this data into dotnet at all. It is simply an update statement. I can't make enough clarity out of your description of what you are trying to do here to give you any real code. Posting the table definition, some sample data and what you expect after this runs would help considerably.

Comment: If you describe this purely in terms of the database ( the tables and what needs to happen) we can provide a single update statement to do what you want, which you might agree considerably simplifies the process (and therefore makes it more maintainable)

Comment: @SeanLange I have added everything my manager gave me, please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have added everything my manager gave me, please let me know if you need any additional information

Comment: All of this kind of thing: "for each of the above, loop through these records" is achievable using joins. Joins are fundamental parts of a database. Again looking at this I think this can be done in one update statement. Can you explain what "add as Zero (0) dollar amount" means? The problem is that instead of posing a problem and asking you to solve it, your manager has posed a bad solution and asked you to implement it

Comment: Also "after each order is processed"?? What is "processed"? Is it just setting processed = 1? What else?

Comment: I notice that you've asked many questions, had many people spend much time answering them, and you have not had the courtesy to mark an answer or respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I want to pose this to prompt you for some clarification and it's not practical in the comments.

First, **close** visual studio and open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the database

We'll build some select statements to get the data back and then we can think about an UPDATE statement

This first query you posted gives you the unprocessed headers for store 195 (straight from your post). I don't know if you want to do this for all stores or not. Paste it into SSMS and run it

```
SELECT H.*
FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader H 
WHERE H.isprocessed = 0 AND H.storetoprocess = N'195'
```

Now, this second query gives you the unprocessed lines against that header that have IsBundleParent='Y'.

Look! No loops!

```
SELECT H.*, L.*
FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader H 
INNER JOIN
dbo.OrderLine L
ON L.InvoiceHeader_Id = H.InvoiceHeader_Id 
WHERE H.isprocessed = 0 AND H.storetoprocess = N'195'
AND L.isprocessed = 0 AND L.IsBundleParent = 'Y'
```

Then in your explanation you have *For each record in the above list query below and add as Zero (0) dollar amount* which makes no sense to me so perhaps you could clarify

Now we'll add the third query in which adds BundleParentLine (which does have inner joins in it already, but it's a pretty strange list of join fields)

```
SELECT H.*, L.*, BPL.*
FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader H 
INNER JOIN
dbo.OrderLine L
ON L.InvoiceHeader_Id = H.InvoiceHeader_Id 
INNER JOIN
dbo.BundleParentLine BPL
ON BPL.OrderLine_Id = L.OrderLine_Id 
AND BPL.LineDetail_Id = L.LineDetail_Id 
AND BPL.LineDetails_Id = L.LineDetails_Id 
AND BPL.InvoiceHeader_Id = L.InvoiceHeader_Id    
WHERE H.isprocessed = 0 AND H.storetoprocess = N'195'
AND L.isprocessed = 0 AND L.IsBundleParent = 'Y'
```

Then in your explanation you have *After Processed, set isprocessed = 1*, but what is 'processed' here? Is it just setting it to processed in the table?

To do that you just write an `UPDATE` statement. Here's one way to do that to update just the header (don't run it though until we understand what you're trying to do). Is the problem here that you want to set header and line to processed at the same time?

```
UPDATE InvoiceHeader
SET Processed = 1
WHERE isprocessed = 0 AND storetoprocess = N'195'
```

The fourth query you have seems to account for the `IsBundleParent <> 'Y'` case

Again, we need to know what *add as Zero (0) dollar amount* and *processed* means to go any further.